# Set CsvEncoder delimiter in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, csv, decode

I want to decode csv files, but some of them have ";" as delimiters which result in faulty objects. With the following code comma separated csv files are decoded properly:

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-csv-and-yaml-encoders-for-serializer

```
// instantiation, when using it as a component
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\CsvEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder()]);

// instantiation, when using it inside the Symfony framework
$serializer = $container->get('serializer');

// encoding contents in CSV format
$serializer->encode($data, 'csv');

// decoding CSV contents
$data = $serializer->decode(file_get_contents('data.csv'), 'csv');
```

I tried setting the context as parameter in the decode function:

```
$context = array(";", '"', "\\", ",");

$data = $serializer->decode(file_get_contents($file), 'csv', $context);
```

and as a parameter in the constructor:

```
$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder($context)]);
```

Both tries without any different result.

**I got it working this way:**

```
$context = [
    CsvEncoder::DELIMITER_KEY => ';',
    CsvEncoder::ENCLOSURE_KEY => '"',
    CsvEncoder::ESCAPE_CHAR_KEY => '\\',
    CsvEncoder::KEY_SEPARATOR_KEY => ',',
];

$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder()]);
$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
$data = $serializer->decode(file_get_contents($file), 'csv', $context);
```

Answer (score 9):

For Symfony 4, the good syntax is :

```
$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder()]);
$datas = $serializer->decode(file_get_contents($csvPath), 'csv', [CsvEncoder::DELIMITER_KEY => ';']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$context = ['csv_delimiter' => [",", '"', "\\", "."] ];
```